# how to check for non null string in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Total newbie python question.
I find myself having to write to the following code

```
s: str
if s is None or len(s) <= 0
```

to check for string validation.

I finally wrote a tiny function to do that for me.

Is there a more pythantic way of doing this?

Comment: I am curious about the function you are mentioning. Would you also post it here, I think it will be useful to have it?

Comment: Other than in C, a string can not be null. A string can be empty and a variable can reference `None`, but that's about it. I would expect type annotations to be able to guarantee that a variable is a `str` and not `None`, where does that fail for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string will be "truthy" if it is not None or has `len > 0`. Simply do the following check:

```py
if s:
  print("The string is valid!")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not s`:

```py
>>> not None
True
>>> not ''
True
>>> not 'foo'
False
```

Answer (score 0):

If your real goal is to find out if `s` is a string, you can use `isinstance()`.

```py
isinstance(s,str)
```

Comment: Why would you think that's the case? OP even type-hinted s to be a string!